# How do I reset the Windows 8.1 Update Start screen background to use the desktop background

Tags: windows-8.1, start-screen

While looking for a way to reset the Sign In screen colour under Windows 8.1 Update, I set the Start screen's background colour to a uniform blue.

How to I reset to use the desktop background (which is what it was doing before)?

Comment: You are interchanging the incorrect term with the correct term.  Do you want to change the Start Screen background or the desktop background?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change windows 8 start menu screen background](http://superuser.com/questions/722686/how-to-change-windows-8-start-menu-screen-background)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the registry setting:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent]
"MotionAccentId_v1.00"=dword:000000db
```